# List exported objects from R package without attaching it

Tags: r, cran

Is there a way to list the objects that a package exports, without actually attaching it? I tried

```
ls(loadNamespace("ggplot2"))
```

However this shows all of the defined and imported objects in this package. Instead I would like to see only the exported names. I.e. I would like the result of

```
library(ggplot2)
ls("package:ggplot2")
```

But without actually attaching the package to my search path.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use documented `getNamespaceExports("ggplot2")`.

Answer (score 6):

Ah found it. The undocumented

```
ls(getNamespaceInfo(mynamespace, "exports"));
```

Seems to do the trick.