# How to find how a package was loaded in R?

Tags: r, dependencies, dependency-management

I just updated all my packages and restarted my system.
Then I loaded RStudio and preceded to run my scripts as normal.

I got an error: `Error in wday(temp_date) : could not find function "wday"`

Searching, I found the `wday` function is part of the lubricate package, and I have the `lubricate` package installed, but not loaded.

So it seems that at least one of my updated packages previously was dependent on the lubricate package, but is not anymore, as a result even though my scripts loaded all the same packages as before, the lubricate package was missed.

So to prevent this is the future I would like to know how to find out what loaded the lubricate package from my script and if possible to know what changed.
I would also like to know all of my package dependencies so I always know that this package loads that and other package so I am not surprised like this anymore.

**Update:**
I found more errors and slowly worked out that many packages and dependencies were not actually updated and had to be installed manually.
I found that `wday` that I am using is from IDateTime from data.table. But once again I am not loading these packages directly, so how can I find out what actually loaded them.
Thanks.

**Update 2:**
Here is my full list of library calls:

```
library(qmao);library(chron);library(tseries);library(iterators);library(erer);
library(corpcor); library(zoo); library(xts); library(quantmod);
library(TTR); library(graphics); library(ggplot2); library(gsee);
library(tseries); library(quantstrat); library(plyr); library(caTools);
library(zoo); library(chron); library(gtools); library(microbenchmark);
library(benchmark); library(rbenchmark); library(utils); library(Rcpp);
library(RcppXts); library(RcppArmadillo); library(gtools); library(rcppbugs);
library(RcppClassic); library(RcppStreams); library(inline); library(RcppEigen);
library(RcppParallel); library(RcppProgress); library(doParallel); library(parallel);
library(foreach); library(doMC); library(doSNOW); library(fGarch); library(FitAR);
library(fUnitRoots); library(dplyr);
```

None of them include lubricate or data.table so still don't know. I suppose I could go 1 by 1 loading each library until the functions work, but I really don't have the time or patience for that. Thanks again.

Comment: (1) `lubridate` vice `lubricate`? (2) `library(lubridate)` or (very often misused) `if (require(lubridate)) ...`. Or (3) you can always use the double-colon format with `lubridate::wday`, and it'll work without `library`/`require` (as long as the package is installed somewhere in your `.libPaths()`).

Comment: It turns out I was not using lubricate, but data.table. Anyway, I know that wday exists in lubricate, at least after it is loaded, but how can I find what package loaded lubricate in the first place. I would love to use :: but I have no idea where the packages come from and would like to minimize dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, you need to trace package dependencies. Errr ... if you load a package and it has a gazillion internal dependencies, you will see none of those available until you explicitly load the library yourself. Some packages re-export some functions (`dplyr` re-exports `magrittr::%>%`). Some packages make the other packages' functions available within their tools, and this is a little more difficult to demonstrate at the moment. Long story short: if you can use `wday` by itself on the console, you likely manually did `library(data.table)` or `library(lubridate)` yourself.

Comment: It *is* certainly possible for another package to call `library(...)`, though this is strongly discouraged. I think this would evidence as you suggest here: a function is in your search-path that you did not explicitly `library` yourself, but I haven't tested it completely yet. If you find packages that add others to your search-path in this manner, it's "not nice" and should likely be raised as an issue to the maintainer.

Comment: Third scenario: a package that *assumes* you have `data.table` installed (whether or not in your search path) has a call to `wday` that is not properly set up as `data.table::wday`. In that case, after you get that error, run `traceback()` and see which call in the stack is flubbing things up.

Comment: @r2evans You should write this as an answer. I assume too that this is probably because of internal dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an R-internals or R-Core guy, so some of this is speculation and understanding on my part.

If a package imports functions from another package, either one-by-one or the whole other-package, then those functions should not be inserted into *your* search path. For example, `dplyr` is a fairly complex package that imports from several other packages and optionally re-exports some of them. For instance, from its [`NAMESPACE`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L459):

```
importFrom(R6,R6Class)
```

but if you `library(dplyr)` and then type in `R6Class`, it reports `Error: object 'R6Class' not found`. However, it *is* visible to `dplyr` functions:

```
> R6Class
Error: object 'R6Class' not found
> debug(dplyr::mutate)
> mutate(mtcars, cyl = 5)
debugging in: mutate(mtcars, cyl = 5)
debug: {
    UseMethod("mutate")
}
Browse[2]> R6Class
function (classname = NULL, public = list(), private = NULL, 
    active = NULL, inherit = NULL, lock_objects = TRUE, class = TRUE, 
    portable = TRUE, lock_class = FALSE, cloneable = TRUE, parent_env = parent.frame(), 
    lock) 
{
...
```

This works now because the search path within `dplyr::mutate` is from `dplyr`'s perspective, not the user's perspective.

Combine with this my doubt (though not certainty) that those packages would call `library(data.table)`, importing the package into ***your*** search path.

More than likely, there is a package imported by one of the packages you just listed (a second-generation dependency-import, I guess) that is improperly referencing `wday` by itself, and it just starts working when some higher package is properly loaded, bringing that function into its effective search path.

I suggest two ways to find what is going wrong:

1. When you see an error, run `traceback()` and look at the stack of function calls; it'll take some sleuthing, but find where that `wday` is being called, find that function in the packages (both exported and internal functions!), and go from there.
2. If all packages are being thorough in announcing packages they import (via `Depends:`, `Imports:`, or perhaps even a mis-used `Suggests:`), then you can hunt down where nested dependencies go with something like this.

   ```r
   pkgs <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(gsub("library\\(([^)]*)\\)", "\\1", "library(qmao);library(chron);library(tseries);library(iterators);library(erer);
   library(corpcor); library(zoo); library(xts); library(quantmod);
   library(TTR); library(graphics); library(ggplot2); library(gsee);
   library(tseries); library(quantstrat); library(plyr); library(caTools);
   library(zoo); library(chron); library(gtools); library(microbenchmark);
   library(benchmark); library(rbenchmark); library(utils); library(Rcpp);
   library(RcppXts); library(RcppArmadillo); library(gtools); library(rcppbugs);
   library(RcppClassic); library(RcppStreams); library(inline); library(RcppEigen);
   library(RcppParallel); library(RcppProgress); library(doParallel); library(parallel);
   library(foreach); library(doMC); library(doSNOW); library(fGarch); library(FitAR);
   library(fUnitRoots); library(dplyr);"), ";")))
   # just so I can search locally on mine without all of those packages
   inst_pkgs <- installed.packages()
   pkgs <- intersect(pkgs, inst_pkgs[,1])

   # inexact but "good enough" for now
   possibles <- Filter(function(a) any(grepl("data.table|lubridate", a)),
                       sapply(pkgs, function(p) unlist(packageDescription(p)[c("Depends","Imports","Suggests")])))
   names(possibles)
   # [1] "dplyr"
   ```

   You can find more info by looking at the full details of that package:

   ```r
   possibles[[1]]["Suggests"]
   #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Suggests 
   # "bit64 (>= 0.9.7), callr (>= 3.1.1), covr (>= 3.0.1), DBI (>=\n0.7.14), dbplyr (>= 1.2.0), dtplyr (>= 0.0.2), ggplot2 (>=\n2.2.1), hms (>= 0.4.1), knitr (>= 1.19), Lahman (>= 3.0-1),\nlubridate (>= 1.7.4), MASS, mgcv (>= 1.8.23), microbenchmark\n(>= 1.4.4), nycflights13 (>= 0.2.2), rmarkdown (>= 1.8), RMySQL\n(>= 0.10.13), RPostgreSQL (>= 0.6.2), RSQLite (>= 2.0),\ntestthat (>= 2.0.0), withr (>= 2.1.1), broom (>= 0.5.1), purrr\n(>= 0.3.0), readr (>= 1.3.1), crayon (>= 1.3.4)"
   ```

Comment: Cool, that works great. dplyr loads lubricate and gsee loads data.table. But,  since the function I need is wday, is it possible to find which packages have wday first? Other than searching on google. Thanks again.

Comment: With respect to a particular perspective, which package is loaded *last* masks the others. This is demonstrated when you do `library(plyr)` and then `library(dplyr)`, when it tells you that `arrange` and friends are masked from `plyr`. This is one reason why packages should always do direct double-colon referencing (`data.table::wday` or `lubridate::wday`) of imported functions, IMHO.

Comment: But I'm not sure what you mean by *"which packages have wday first"* ... if you mean "which function does a particular package intend to use", you can only *guess* from the rest of the package's source code or ask the maintainer directly. If you mean "what is the actual order of packages loaded", well, that's hard to tell without reading the source.

Comment: First, I mean for the script I need to know that I am looking for either the data.table or lubricate function, which I only know from google and other working machines. How can the script be adapted to search for which packages have the wday function first then see how those packages are loaded. I tried entering "wday" in the code and got no results. Thanks again.

Comment: R findFunction only works on loaded packages, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397193/how-to-find-the-package-name-in-r-for-a-specific-function talks about the sos package which searches online for functions, but for me it cannot open a connection. I am hoping your script can be modified to look at all installed packages to do the search. Is this something I should ask in a separate question? Thanks.

Comment: My script does look at all installed packages: `inst_pkgs <- installed.packages()`. I don't understand where you are going with this. If you want to find what package is depending on (Depends or Imports), then I think my answer addresses that. If you really want to find all packages that include a function named `wday`, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9658518 (`getNamespaceExports`) ... but I thought your intent was to find which package was bringing `data.table` or `lubridate` into your search path.

Comment: I did want data.table or lubricate, but only because I was looking for wday. I didn't know what was possible. I ideally I would have findMyFunction("wday") and it would give me: "data.table" "lubricate" |  "dyplr" "gsee"  meaning wday exists in data.table and lubricate, but is accessed from dyplr and gsee. Should this be a separate question.

Comment: Okay ... one problem with that approach is that you assume all package authors will name this function `wday`, where what you may want is more of a fuzzy search. If you run `help.search("weekday")`, you'll find many functions that reference that word or a word similar to it, including the functions `base::weekdays`, `chron::days`, and `timeDate::isWeekday`. It's an imperfect search, and for a better search you may need to hire an assistant or minion :-)

Comment: But if a package you *need* is using `wday` (from either package) internally, there's not much you can do to assuage it other than (1) not use that package, or (2) convince the package maintainer to use something else. Neither option is "great and fast".

Comment: Yes, but my code worked a day ago, today I have function `wday` is not found. I just need to find it as fast as possible. Before wday, I was using another weekdays function that stopped working (maybe from base) so I found `wday`. I am trying to make it fast and simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193848/discussion-between-michaele-and-r2evans).